# Can I keep a session when leaving the page (and return later)?

Tags: php, session

For reasons out of my control I need to send form data to an other server and return back right away after it has been processed and alter the state of an entry in my local data base when returning.

In principle it works fine but when I return it seems my session has been terminated and I need to login again in order to reach the page I want to reach. Unfortunately, this hinders my script to actually inform my data base that the external data base has processed the data. Of course I could open up the page for public access but I want to avoid that. An other option would be to send a key with the form data and to only bypass the need for a login if the returned key is correct.

But is there a way of telling my session to only terminate after a certain time instead of when leaving the page? (Of course I want to keep the possibility to deliberately terminate the session on logout.)

I just realised that the problem seems to occur on Firefox on Windows and on Mac but not on my GNU/Linux system. There I stay logged in when leaving and returning to the web page. This is the reason why at first I didn't know that people could have this problem.

Comment: To help you we need to know how you store your session in the browser. In detail, with code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'm not sure what you mean. I created a session in PHP with session_start() and saved the needed value in a session variable. To my knowledge all this happens on the server itself. How can I influence how browsers handle sessions?
I now had the idea that maybe the problem is that the external page also creates a session. I just removed this on the other server since there I do not need any session variable. Hopefully this is a working solution.

Comment: There are many ways to initiate a session. `session_start()` is just one way. Hence my question.

Comment: Staying there when you go and come back is pretty much what a session does by definition - in HTTP, there isn't actually any concept of "entering" and "leaving" a site, just a sequence of requests. So, something more specific must be happening that is making the browser not send the session cookie on the "returning" request.

Comment: Does your `session_start()` have any options set? Also [session_get_cookie_params()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php) might be of interest.

Comment: No, I don't have any options set.

Maybe there can be only one session for each browser tab at once. My colleague will test if removing the session_start() on the external page does the trick. (Since I don't own a system with Windows or OSX I can't test it myself.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that also creating a session on the external page ended the original session (at least in Firefox on Windows and on OSX). After removing the `session_start()` on the external page the session stays alive as intended.
It seems there can be only one active session in any given tab and creating a new session terminates the old one. (However, this termination only happens on Windows and OSX but not on Firefox ESR GNU/Linux.)

It is strange that the default setting for session cookies is to be deleted if a new session is started (if not on Firefox ESR on GNU/Linux).

What ever the true explanation is: this is the behaviour I discovered.

Comment: What do you mean by (and how do you do that) starting a new session

Comment: The session you are talking about is maintained by a cookie. If the browser is set to delete cookies on exit, you will loose the session, otherwise there is no reason why the session would disappear until it naturally times out from the server timeout setting

Comment: Testing showed me that the default setting for Firefox on Windows and OSX seems to be that it ends a session as soon as a new one is created in any given tab.
Originally I also created a session on the external page (despite not actually needing one there) that processes my form data (the same way as on my local page). After removing `session_start()` from my external page the first session stays alive.

Comment: Check the specific cookie settings on each of the browsers you used in your, i believe, flawed test.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the systems I am talking about. Therefore, I can't really check the settings there. The odd thing is that only on my system I have set very strict rules. I delete all cookies each time I close the browser. The Windows and OSX systems do certainly use the default settings.

Comment: The conclusion has to be that your browser settings cause the session cookie to be deleted.

Comment: I agree. But it is strange that this is the default and that even the strictest available setting for deleting those cookies on Linux is less radical than that. I fear something else is going on but I don't have an explanation.